# Line up contents of multiple <p> tags in 2 ways

Tags: html, css

So, basically I have the following:

```
<h5 className='admin-notice'><span className={`${klass}teal`}>Teal</span> - Random Text one</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><span className={`${klass}blue`}>Purple</span> - Some other random text</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><span className={`${klass}red`}>Red</span> - Hey there random</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><span className={`${klass}grey`}>Grey</span> - hi</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><span className={`${klass}yellow`}>Yellow</span> - this is random</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><span className={`${klass}green`}>Green</span> - its howdie doodie time</h5>
```

So each element has text to the left followed by a break, `-`, and then more text. I want it so all the text for each element after the `-` begins at the same spot and is lined up. How do I do this? Below is a screenshot of how it is currently looking.
[image]

Comment: Define a width for the `<span>` or get the width of each of them and then make all the widths that of the greatest with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a simple and flexible way to do this. You could use spaces, but that wouldn't work well if you wanted to add more items.

I would use a table with two columns:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h5 className='admin-notice'>
                <span className={`${klass}teal`}>Teal</span> - 
            </h5>    
        </td>   
        <td>
            <h5 className='admin-notice'>
                Random Text one
            </h5>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

You can also adjust the margin and alignment in each cell. `td { padding: 1px; text-align: left; }`. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) has lots of information on Tables and other HTML & CSS elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your span elements inside p elements with fixed width and inline-block display. For example:

```
<h5 className='admin-notice'><p style="width:300px; display:inline-block; margin:0;" ><span className={`${klass}teal`}>Teal</span></p>- Random Text one</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><p style="width:300px; display:inline-block; margin:0;" ><span className={`${klass}blue`}>Purple</span></p> - Some other random text</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><p style="width:300px; display:inline-block; margin:0;" ><span className={`${klass}red`}>Red</span></p> - Hey there random</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><p style="width:300px; display:inline-block; margin:0;" ><span className={`${klass}grey`}>Grey</span></p> - hi</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><p style="width:300px; display:inline-block; margin:0;" ><span className={`${klass}yellow`}>Yellow</span></p> - this is random</h5>
<h5 className='admin-notice'><p style="width:300px; display:inline-block; margin:0;" ><span className={`${klass}green`}>Green</span></p> - its howdie doodie time</h5>
```

NOTE: This is just an example, use whatever width suits your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use manual width to your `span` element and set the `display` property to `inline-block`. This should work:

```css
.alignText {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
}
```

```html
<h3><span class="alignText">Teal - </span><span>Random Text one</span></h3>
<h3><span class="alignText">Purple - </span><span>Some other random text</span></h3>
<h3><span class="alignText">Red - </span><span>Hey there random</span></h3>
<h3><span class="alignText">Grey - </span><span>hi</span></h3>
<h3><span class="alignText">Yellow - </span><span>this is random</span></h3>
<h3><span class="alignText">Green - </span><span>its howdie doodie time</span></h3>
```